Deploy json-server with base-64 string in typicode free version
I have a react project which has a backend database created using json-server. The json-server contains some normal string as well as bas64 converted string. Lines of code are maximum 300. I was following the below link to depoy the db.json file:  https://dev.to/nikita_guliaev/deploying-create-react-app-with-json-server-as-backend-to-github-3pp9
But whenever I am trying to see my json database according to the blog, it is throwing error as:
Error
maxContentLength size of 10000 exceeded

I found a way to create a server.js file after npm init and installing json-server. The code is:
const jsonServer = require("json-server"); 
const server = jsonServer.create(); 
const router = jsonServer.router("db.json"); 
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults(); 
const port = 1000; 

server.use(middlewares); 
server.use(router); 
server.listen(port);

but still it showing the error, I found that it is an IIS issue, but how to solve that?
